# How to config a schedule query after another schedule has completed in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 3 tables: A B and C. I scheduled a daily query on A with results appended to B. And I wanna scheduled another daily query on B, the query should run after the previous one had  completed. How can I do it? The Big Query can only schedule query at Fix Time.

When the first query has finished, the second query should be trigger and run.

Comment: Have you tried using Cloud Composer to schedule your queries?

Comment: @KiranKumarB aha sounds good, I'll try it

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery is a data warehouse and does not support triggers unfortunately.

I have not used this as just leave 30 mins between scheduled queries but Google cloud appears to offer a solution

https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/how-trigger-cloud-run-actions-bigquery-events

Answer (score 0):

As @Kiran suggested you can try using cloud composer for scheduled queries. You can view this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/trigger-dags) on how triggering DAGs works both scheduled and manually.

> Airflow provides the following ways to trigger a DAG: 
> **Trigger on a schedule.** When you create a DAG, you specify a schedule for it. Airflow triggers the DAG automatically based on the specified scheduling parameters.
> **Trigger manually.** You can trigger a DAG manually from the Airflow UI, or by running an Airflow CLI command from gcloud.
> **Trigger in response to events.** The standard way to trigger a DAG in response to events is to use a sensor.